# How to share one phtml file variable output to another phtml file

Tags: magento2, phtml

In custom modules, I want to share my **module A** output variable **$value = "one"** to **module B**, print like **$value** How to share this?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the setData() & getData() function.**

**Step: 1**

Module A
Add below code in Module A phtml file

**A.phtml**

```
$data = array('value'=> 'one');

<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("VendorName\ModuleName\Block\CustomBlock")->setData($data)->setTemplate("VendorName_ModuleName::path/B.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

**Step: 2**

Module B
Add below code in Module B phtml file

**B.phtml**

```
$value = $this->getData('value ');
```

Comment: In module A my value https://paste.ofcode.org/Ene6SkjRfY3vCCkeCcDADK

Comment: How to share storeCode to my module B

Comment: You can pass data using array format.

Comment: Can i get some code help?